# Powershell check if file exists and replace it with new copy

Tags: powershell, select-object

I'm trying to check if a directory exists, and if it does replace all files in that directory with updated files from another directory.

```
$path = "C:\mypath\config"
if([System.IO.Directory]::Exists($path)){
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Select-Object "Name"
    ForEach ($File in $files)
    {
        Copy-Item -Path "C:\tmp\$File" -Destination "$path\$File.txt"
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error with the Copy-Item command because the $File is returning @{Name=filename} instead of just the name of the file. I've tried using $File.name, $File.basename, etc. but none of those appear to work. How do I get Powershell to not wrap the filename in "@{Name=}"?

Comment: I would recommend using `Robocopy` for copying files.

Comment: Just keep your pipeline going: `Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Copy-Item -Destination {"$path\$_.txt"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it almost right, you just need to use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter for `Select-Object`.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Name"
```

This will get you an array of strings that are the names of the files.

What you had previously is an array of custom objects with the Name property copied from the file-info objects.

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to access the name is to reference the name property directly:

```
$files = (Get-ChildItem -Path $path).name
```